# Proguard not generating anything in build/outputs/mapping/release

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, proguard

I've migrated my app from ADT to Android Studio as it become the Official IDE.

But I recently found out that I can decompilate it, and my source is clear.

I spent A LOT OF TIME in eclipse to obfuscate my apk, so I still have my Proguard File, this is the good

proguard-project.txt:

```
 ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
 -optimizationpasses 5
 -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
 -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
 -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
 -dontpreverify
 -verbose
 -dump class_files.txt 
 -printseeds seeds.txt 
 -printusage unused.txt 
 -printmapping mapping.txt 
 -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*


 #-injars      bin/classes
 #-injars      libs
 #-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar



 -allowaccessmodification
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
 -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
 -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable, LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable
 -repackageclasses ''


 -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
 -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
 -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
 -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
 -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
 -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
 -dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

 -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
     public <init>(android.content.Context);
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
     public void set*(...);
 }

 # Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
 # is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
 -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID;
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
     java.lang.Object readResolve();
 }


 # Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
 -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }
 -keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
 }

 -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
     public static <fields>;
 }

 -keepclassmembers class * {
     @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
 }


 -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 }


 -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 }


 # Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
 # through introspection.
 -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
   public static <fields>;
 }


 # Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
 -keepclassmembers enum * {
     public static **[] values();
     public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
 }


 -keep public class * {
     public protected *;
 }

 ##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------


 ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
 # Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
 # removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
 -keepattributes Signature


 # Gson specific classes
 -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
 #-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }


 # Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
 -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }


 ##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

 ##---------------Begin proguard configuration for Google Maps --------------------

 -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

 -keep class org.** { *; }
 -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
     protected Object[][] getContents();
 }

 -keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
     public static final *** NULL;
 }

 -keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
 -keepclassmembernames class * {
     @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
 }


 -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
 -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

 ##---------------End proguard configuration for Google Maps --------------------

 ##---------------Begin proguard configuration for my libs  -----------------------
 -keep class com.todddavies.components.progressbar.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.todddavies.components.progressbar.**

 -dontwarn org.apache.**

 -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
 }
 -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
     static ** CREATOR;
 }
 -keep class com.myapp.mobile.Pdv.** { *; }
 -keep interface  com.myapp.mobile.Pdv.** { *; }

 #Disable logging

 -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
     public static *** d(...);
     public static *** v(...);
     public static *** i(...);
 }
 -keep class com.myapp.mobile.vo.Captura { *; }
 -keep class com.myapp.mobile.vo.Formulario { *; }
 -keep class com.myapp.mobile.vo.Metrica { *; }
 -keep class com.myapp.mobile.vo.Pdv { *; }
 -keep class com.myapp.mobile.vo.Proyecto { *; }
 -keep class com.myapp.mobile.vo.Producto { *; }
```

my build.gradle is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile project(':progressWheel')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
}
```

I saw several post, all of them say you have to activate it with :

minifyEnabled true
but mine is already activated...

I also realized thanks to @Robert Rowntree that build/outputs/mapping/release was empty after running ./gradlew clean assembleRelease

Still, I can't get Proguard work??? No way I publish my app without proguard!!!

Any Idea???

EDIT 1: When I run gradlew build, I get BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: **1)** Remove the "common to all projects" proguard code. It's already included by `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` (verify the file if it still is appropriate though, or keep what you don't find there). **2)** Why don't you compile against plain "22"? Never really understood the point of compiling against Google APIs. Can you explain in comment?

Comment: 1. Proguard.txt has nothing inside. 2. I will not change API level at this stage of development, I will update it after stable version is released. Anyway, it will not resolve my problem, just create me new ones. 3. I compile with Google APIs because I run Google Maps in my apps ( and you need to run Google Play Services for that)

Comment: **1.** There is no `proguard.txt`. Only files with rules that are read are `proguard-android.txt` from SDK dir and `proguard-project.txt` from your project dir (according to your setup). I suggested to cleanup the project proguard rules as it looks it originally included the common rules as well. **2.** That's certainly wise. **3.** You are including all *latest* (yes, dynamic) Google Play Services API by this line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`. `Google Inc.:Google APIs:21` is used just for setting up emulator with Play services support afaik.

Comment: 1.Ok, my mistake, but it seems to be only an "optimization", should not solve anything. Anyway, I fixed it, tx. As mentionned in point 2, you might be right for Google APIs, but now is not the time to move something, if I don't think it will resolve my Proguard problem!

Comment: I was just asking. Anyway please post how you fixed it as an answer for others. Thank you!

Comment: I did not fix anything yet! Proguard is still not obfuscing!

Comment: `Anyway, I fixed it, tx.` I must've misunderstood. When you run `gradlew build` from command line in your project root do you see proguard related tasks in the output?

Comment: Nop, I can't see anything in output folder

Comment: OK, if you run build and there's nothing in the output, there's no problem with proguard, but the build process in general. Again: open the command  line in your project root and run `gradlew build`. This will build all variants (debug and release) of your app and if there's an error you will see it in the console *output*. Add that error at the end of your original question.

Comment: I've made the edit to my post. Build is failing. What I don't understand is how can it fail with command line if it doesn't fail when generating Signed APK from Android Studio

Comment: Ok, I will fix lint errors

Comment: Ok, I fixed some Lint Errors, but there were too much, so I unabled Lint Checking by adding lintOptions {  abortOnError false  }
Now Build is successful, but I still don't have nothing in output folder

Comment: You can ignore the warnings but you should fix all the errors before release because they are likely to cause exceptions. The output `.apk`s should be in `<project>/<app-module>/build/outputs/apk`. Does the build fail on something else?

Comment: I have the generated apk in this folder built successfully. I just have nothing in outputs/mapping... So I guess while this folder is empty, proguard is not obfuscating my apk

Comment: You keep mentioning `outputs/mapping`, what exactly are you expecting to be there? I'm asking because I've never heard of it. Just take the release apk from `outputs/apk` and try decompiling it. The release apk should be obfuscated because you enabled proguard in `build.gradle` for release builds and the build process succeeded. (Try comparing apk file sizes when proguard is enabled and disabled.)

Comment: Good point! Don't know what I am expecting, my app still doesn't get obfuscated. Still, when I delete content of Proguard file, I get errors, so it is showing that it is using it. File size : Debug 3.6MB Release 3.4 I can see it obfuscate all the code that is not my project ( libs, etc) but my project is clean code inside :(

Comment: it seems to be a proguard.txt problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted those line in proguard.txt and my apk has a little bit more obfuscation.
I'd like a bit more, but this is a good start !

```
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```